# SAP / DB2 for LUW 11.1 Finding out process that is creating high number of TLOG entries

Tags: database-performance, db2-luw, sap-erp

I have problem with replicating data from DB2 LUW (that is DB for SAP ECC app).
Replication procedure utilize DB2 low level API DB2 Log Reader.
https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.1?topic=apis-db2readlog-read-log-records

Recently I can see that I can't read anymore logs in timely manner (I am connecting with Express Route between DB2 and Software that reads log so network is super good).

What I was able to identify so far is that there was 4 hours interval where reading logs were getting slower. I was also replicating `AUFK` (SAP ECC table) and saw every 4 hours enormous number of UPDATES. We were able to find out job on SAP ECC and disable it.

Now I am spotting different interval.. (probably other job on different table)

Is there a way (on SAP ECC or directly on DB2) to verify which table is having most DML(writes) or causing high consumption of log space?

I would like to get statistics like top 10 :

TABLE Name || % of Daily Log utilization

or

TABLE Name || No of Inserts || No of Updates || No of Deletes

What would be even better to maybe get the stats by Hour so I can associate it with some Job that is running.

Note: I don't have access to DB2 or SAP ECC and need to give some kind of guideline to team what I expect them to run on SAP ECC or DB2 side.

Comment: This is a database-administration question. It is not about programming. You might want to use instead dba.stackexchange.com . Db2-LUW v11.1 has many views/functions to give such statistics, and the SAP cockpit also has access to these, so any competent DBA or SAP cockpit user should be able to quickly help.

Comment: From SAP ECC perspective, if you don't give any information but "job" and "AUFK", it's impossible to help.

Comment: @SandraRossi This is what I was afraid of. The only additional thing I can provide is timeframe when i see the spike of latency on my end and drop in network throughput. 

I would know the table if i can have access to all tables but I can't get this.

In Test system i can;t spot this behavior so I am stuck